# Is there a cap on total AVs?

Tags: pokemon-lets-go

In Let's Go, AVs (Awakening Value) have replaced EVs (Effort Value). In previous games, there was a cap on the total number of EVs you could acquire across all stats which was distinctly less than the total of each EV stat cap. EVs capped out at 255 per stat, IIRC, whereas the total number of EVs you could acquire was 510. Clearly, 510 wasn't enough to max EVs in every stat.

Therefore, there was a min-maxing meta where you'd typically focus all of your available EVs on two different stats. Does this same mechanic apply to AVs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no overall cap. The only maximum is 200 per stat, so a pokémon with 200 AVs in each stat (and thus 1200 overall) is perfectly legal.